# Extending a reducer to different pages with slightly different data

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this page where the tasks corresponding to the project queried, and the actions corresponding to the tasks are listed.

So, for a url of `/project/5`, the page will look like this:

```
Project 5 Title, Due Date 

Task #1 : Task 1 title
     Action #1: Action 1 for task 1 title

Task #2 : Task 2 title
     Action #1: Action 1 for task 2 title
     Action #2: Action 2 for task 2 title
```

I have a `reducer`, called `projectReducer` for managing the state of the page I described above. In this reducer, I have the following items (`pageDataId` refers to the id of the project queried):

```
pageDataId: 0, //id of the project queried
pageData: [] as any,
tasks: [] as any,
actions: [] as any,
error: null,
loading: false,
```

This works fine. In a different page, I want to display the comments to the actions, like:

```
Action #1 Title
     Comment #1
         Reply #1 to comment #1
```

I wonder If I should I go ahead and use the same `reducer` with `comments: [] as any` added:

```
pageDataId: 0, // will be id of the action being loaded
pageData: [] as any,// will include action title, and an array of the ids of the comments
tasks: [] as any, // will be empty
actions: [] as any,// will be empty
comments: [] as any,
error: null,
loading: false,
```

Or, should I create a separate `reducer` for this page where the comments are displayed:

```
pageDataId: 0, // will be id of the action being loaded
pageData: [] as any,// will include action title, and an array of the ids of the comments
comments: [] as any,
error: null,
loading: false,
```

Which option would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducer is about [merging action data to state](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers).

> Reducers specify how the application's state changes in response to actions sent to the store.

If you have several reducer and combine them using `combineReducer`, typically state will be divided in parts on reducer boundaries, but still will be single.

From page perspective it doesn't matter how many reducers you have and how your store is divided. All this will be handled in `mapStateToProps`.

With single reducer you'll have `mapStateToProps` like this

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return { 
        pageDataId: state.pageDataId,
        comments: state.comments
    }
}
```

with several reducers `mapStateToProps` will look like this

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return { 
        // Assuming that pageDataId and comments processed by different reducers
        pageDataId: state.reducer1.pageDataId,
        comments: state.reducer2.comments
    }
}
```

Also take in account that it is bad idea to store same information (like `pageData`) in several places in your store. It can quickly become a nightmare to find why data is updated on one page but stay stale on another.

So in general I recommend to use single store in your situation and query different properties on different pages.

You may divide store in parts, but try not to duplicate data in different reducers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then, for example if `comments` are used in two different pages. When, displaying them in one page, I should first check if `comments` are already loaded from the database. If not, I can fetch them from the database, but if loaded, then there is no need to do anything. Is that right?

Comment: Also, in `mapStateToProps` so we can call different `reducers` right? Because, then it is not possible to load different data from the state.

Comment: Yes to both questions (not 'call'reducer, but access data stored in part of store which is processed by reducer), . Redux is "Single source of thruth" (https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles#single-source-of-truth), so `state` is available as a whole to every component.